# Is there a Git builtin that stages all the files (including deleted files)?

Tags: git

It is possible to add all changed files and added files by using `git add .`.

It is possible to add all deleted files by using `git add -u`.

Is there a builtin Git command that adds all files (i.e. changed files, added files and deleted files)?

I know I could create an alias, I just wonder if there is a builtin command for that.

I've tried `git add . -u` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_options) of `git add` says:

> **OPTIONS**
>
> `<pathspec>…`
>
> Files to add content from. Fileglobs (e.g. `*.c`) can be given to add all matching files. Also a leading directory name (e.g. `dir` to add `dir/file1` and `dir/file2`) can be given to update the index to match the current state of the directory as a whole (e.g. specifying `dir` will record not just a file `dir/file1` modified in the working tree, a file `dir/file2` added to the working tree, but also a file `dir/file3` removed from the working tree.
>   *Note that older versions of Git used to ignore removed files; `use --no-all` option if you want to add modified or new files but ignore removed ones.*

It sounds like it matches your request. All you have to do is to use:

```
git add .
```

If it doesn't work on your system maybe you are using an older version of `git`; see the last sentence in the quoted text (the emphasis is mine).

That sentence is displayed in the documentation for `git` versions `2.0.0` and newer. I guess the behaviour changed on version `2.0` and the versions `1.*` are the "older versions" referred in the text.

Use `git --version` to see what version do you use. Upgrade your `git` if possible to get this functionality and other improvements.